# Characterization of $\ell^q$ sequences

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm working on a solution for this one:

Let $x:=(x_n)_n \subset \mathbb{C}^\mathbb{N}.$ Suppose that for any $y\in \ell^p, p\in [1,+\infty],$ the series $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}x_ny_n$ converges. Prove that $(x_n)_n \in \ell^q$ for $q\in [1,+\infty]$ satisfying $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q} = 1.$

I tried to prove the statement for the three cases in the following way, but don't come so far..

- $p=\infty :$ Let $(y_n)_n\in \ell^\infty$, so we have $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|y_n|<\infty$ and that the series $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}x_ny_n$ converges. Now I have to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|<\infty$ to get $(x_n)_n \in \ell^1.$
- $p=1:$ I got the hint to construct a sequence $(y_n)_n \in \ell^1$ such that the sequence $x_ny_n$ does not converge to $0.$
- $p\in(1,\infty):$ here we should apply the Banach Steinhaus Theorem to a well chosen family of linear maps $T_N: \ell^p\to\mathbb{C},N\in\mathbb{N}.$

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $0\ne z\in \Bbb C$ let $z'=|z|^{q-2}\bar z,$ and let $0'=0.$ Note that $|z'|^p=zz'= |z|^q.$

Suppose $x\not \in l_q.$ Then there is a strictly increasing sequence $(M_j)_{j\in \Bbb N}$ in $\Bbb N$ such that $$F(n)=\sum_{j=M_{2n-1}}^{M_{2n}} |x_j|^q>2^n$$ for each $n\in \Bbb N.$

For $n\in \Bbb N$ and $M_{2n-1}\leq j\leq M_{2n}$ let $y_j=(x_j)'/F(n).$ Let $y_j=0$ for all other $j\in \Bbb N.$

We have $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|y_k|^p=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=M_{2n-1}}^{M_{2n}}|x_j|^q/F(n)^{p}=$$ $$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}F(n)^{1-p}<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{n(1-p)}<\infty$$ because $1-p<0.$

We have $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_ky_k=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=M_{2n-1}}^{M_{2n}}x_j(x_j)'/F(n)=$$ $$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1=\infty.$$

Remarks. Treating $x$ as a function  that sends each $y\in l_p$ to $\sum_jx_jy_j, $ we cannot assume $x$ is continuous. But  let $u(n)=(u(n)_j)_j\in l_p$ where $u(n)_j=y_j$ for $M_{2n-1}\leq M_{2n}$ and $u(n)_j=0$ for all other $j$. Then  $\sum_nu(n)=(y_j)_j\in l_p$ and also $\sum_nx(u(n))=x(\sum_nu(n))=\infty$.